# to store the values in nsarray objective-c

Tags: ios

My code:

```
dict=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    dict= _array;
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);


     colorimage = [dict objectAtIndex:0];
    [_b1 setBackgroundImage:colorimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


     colorimage1 = [dict objectAtIndex:1];
     [_b2 setBackgroundImage:colorimage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     colorimage2 = [dict objectAtIndex:2];
    [_b3 setBackgroundImage:colorimage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      colorimage3 = [dict objectAtIndex:3];
     [_b4 setBackgroundImage:colorimage3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  int  j=0;


}
-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender{
    k++;
    [img addObject:colorimage];




    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self check];

}
```

while clicking the button1 it need to store the data of image in NSMutableaArray .I need to compare two array .So how to store the value of image in NSMutableArray in Objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

To store image in array:

```
NSMutableArray * imagesArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[imagesArray  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[imagesArray  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];  
[imagesArray  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]];
```

Compare two arrays:

```
if ([array1 isEqualToArray:array2])
{
    NSLog(@"equal");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Not equal");
}
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) For a code block, either put four (additional) blanks before each line, or mark the block and use the "code button" (`{}`) from the post editor tool bar. I scorn blank lines in code that do *not* improve readability by separating something not otherwise separated.